# set preloader image to swf

Tags: jquery, ajax, flash, preloader

i have a html file containing a swf flash intro of about 3 mb

i want that until the swf is fully loaded an loading preloader is displayed using jquery or ajax .how to set this preloader please provide code for these

thanks in advance

i am using following code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('embed').ready(function(){
        $('img').hide();
          });
   });
     </script>

 </head>

 <body >
 <div id="loaddata">

  <img src="loading.gif"  />
  <embed src="red.swf" width="100%" height="100%" ></embed>



 </div>

 </body>
</html>


but it is not working
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     HTML code ( where you want to add the embed code )



    <div style="display:none" id="dvloader"><img src="loading.gif" /></div>
```

Jquery code

```
 $(function() {

            $("#dvloader").show();
            $(".block1").load("swf.html", function(){ $("#dvloader").hide(); });
            return false;

    });
```

Comment: did you use the another page contain the SWF

Comment: i dont require button , i just want thak as the swf loads complete the loading image is removed